# Call Activity's method on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have an Activity with 2 buttons. A play and a pause button.
When this activity gets in the background, which means when the onStop() method has bean called, this creates a permanent notification that is only destroyed when the activity is resumed.
The notification does provide the play and pause buttons too. How do I call the activity's play() and pause() methods when the notification's buttons are clicked?
I really have no clue on how to address that issue.
I'm using a `RemoteViews` to construct a custom layout. And I know you can call 
`setOnClickPendingIntent()` to bind an Intent to a view.

big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your advise by writting a Service that receives all input from The Notification. I then use the `LocalBroadcastManager` to send appropriate message to a `BroadcastReceiver`, which is responsible for updating the notification. The Activity also has a inner `BroadcastReceiver`. That way both receivers receive intent from the Service and can update their UIs independently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling activity methods, you can use a service to initialize a media player instance and play or pause by passing intent extras. This way you would have more and easier control over the player.

Comment: Hi @Manas Shrestha. In fact I have a counter in my activity so the user sees how the time is going down second after second. If I move the play() and pause() methods to the service, how would I be able the update the UI?

Comment: @EdyBaviloouk You can use ResultReceiver to send the progress back to the activity.